# Salvar dados em um arquivo csv

Tags: python

Estou tentando salvar dados em um arquivo csv oriundos de campos:

```
def inserir():
    camp1 = str(ed1.get())
    camp2 = str(ed2.get())
    camp3 = str(ed3.get())

     with open("contatos.csv","w") as _file:
         _file.write("Nome;tel;endereço")
         _file.write(camp1)
         _file.write(camp2)
         _file.write(camp3)

return None
```

Comment: E qual é a duvida? Edite a pergunta e seja mais claro.

Comment: No caso a primeira linha esta saindo certinho, mas os dados que no caso o usuário digitados pelo que no caso são armazenados na nas variáveis camp, no máximo consigo colocar uma a baixo da outra na coluna nome.

Comment: Segue minha sugestao e adicione essa informacao na pergunta, clicano ali em EDITAR, assim fica mais facil entender a pergunta sem ter que ler aqui nos comentarios.

Comment: Já tentou usar o .writelines() ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não me lembro se writelines funciona com variáveis, mas basicamente é isso.

```
 fh = open(“contatos.csv”,”w”) 
 linhas_de_texto = [camp1, camp2, camp3] 
 fh.writelines(linhas_de_texto) 
 fh.close()
```

Você ali estava tentando escrever apenas uma variável linha por linha

Answer (score -1):

consegui resolver adicionei

```
file.writelines(";".join([camp1,camp2,camp3]))
```